# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2} $ convergence test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2} $$ ratio vs comparison. What would you need to evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{(n+1)^2}}{\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2}}$$ for the ratio test?

Comment: Know any other tests? :)

Comment: Divergence, comparison, integral, ratio, root, Dirichlet's, and alternating series tests @JohnBrevik

Comment: Good. This one involves powers. Which of the above suggests itself?

Comment: The root test, I guess you get $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$ and you can use l'hopital's rule on $e^{lim_{n\to\infty} n\ln{\frac{n}{n+1}}}$

Comment: Perfect! I trust you can clean it up from here :)

Answer (score 1):

can we apply the root test?  let $$ y = a_n^{1/n} = \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n, \ln y = n \ln \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right) = n \ln\left(1- \frac 1{n+1}\right)= n \left(- \frac 1{n+1} + \cdots\right) \to -1$$ as $n \to \infty.$  therefore $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n = \frac 1e<1 $$ and the series is convergent by the root test.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison, using equivalents as it is a series with positive terms. Set $$u_n=\Bigl(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\Bigr)^{n^2}=\Bigl(1+\dfrac 1n\Bigr)^{-n^2} $$
Then $$\ln u_n=-n^2\ln \Bigl(1+\dfrac 1n\Bigr)=-n^2\Bigl(\frac 1n-\frac 1{2n^2}+o\Bigl(\frac 1{n^2}\Bigr)\Bigr)=-n+\frac 12+o(1),$$
hence $$u_n=\mathrm e^{-n+\tfrac 12+o(1)}=\frac{\sqrt{\mathrm e}}{\mathrm e^n}\mathrm e^{o(1)}$$
This shows that $u_n\sim_{\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{\mathrm e}}{\mathrm e^n}$. By the comparison test with a geometric series, $\sum u_n$ is convergent.